# Creating a python script to open ipconfig and use commands with it

Tags: python

I have wifi problems frequently, so I decided to create a Python 3 script to execute the following commands on a Windows 10 command line tool:

```
ipconfig/flushdns
ipconfig/release
ipconfig/renew
```

As I understand, I need to use either the *os* module, or the *subprocess* module to make it work. I just don't know how to execute the commands after invoking ipconfig.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why not a `bat`ch file? What you have is a valid one if you put it in a `.bat` file.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html
"call" is the answer

Comment: thanks for the help, I did make a bat file after creating the script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **[subprocess.call](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call)** method for this

```
import subprocess

print subprocess.call(["ipconfig", "/flushdns"], shell=True)
print subprocess.call(["ipconfig", "/release"], shell=True)
print subprocess.call(["ipconfig", "/renew"], shell=True)
```